# R : using filter in a for loop and change the data value

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr, filter

I have a list called 'col_missing' like below.

```
col_missing <- list(
  RAgeCat = c(-1, 8)
  , Married = c(-1, 9)
  , skipmeal = c(-1, 8, 9)
)
```

and I want to filter the dataframe if the column has above values, and replace them as NA. Below code is working but if it is in a for loop, it is not working.

Working

```
temp <- df %>%  
  filter(skipmeal %in% col_missing$skipmeal)
temp$skipmeal <- NA
```

Not working

```
for (col in names(col_missing)) {
  temp <- df %>%
    filter(col %in% col_missing$col)
  temp$col <- NA
}
```

Could you tell me how to do this in a for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may do this using `across` and modify the values without any `filter`ing

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>%
    mutate(across(all_of(names(col_missing)),
     ~ replace(.x, .x %in% col_missing[[cur_column()]], NA)))
```

---

In the `for` loop, `temp` is getting updated in each iteration.  Perhaps it should be created outside  Also, use `[[` instead of `$` i.e. `col_missing[[col]]` instead of `col_missing$col`

If we need to `filter` and create multiple datasets in a `list`

```
library(purrr)
imap(col_missing, ~ df %>%
         filter(.data[[.y]] %in% .x) %>%
         mutate(!! .y := NA)
)
```